# Adding xUnit to an existing Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xunit

I'm trying to get the grips with xUnit testing framework. I'm new with C# and the ASP.NET framework,

I created a project with

```
dotnet new webapi -o TodoApi
```

Then I added the xUnit package with

```
dotnet add package xunit
dotnet add package xunit.runner.visualstudio
```

And finally

```
dotnet test
```

Then I got this error

```
Program.cs(14,28): error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point. [/Users/gecko/code/TodoApi/TodoApi.csproj]
```

Comment: This may answer your question...https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/

Comment: You should place the tests into separate project

Comment: The title of that blog post is *[Fixing the error "Program has more than one entry point defined" for console apps containing xUnit tests](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/)*.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with [NUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) (no resolution yet).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Your tests should reside in another project that references (depends on) the tested project. If you have an web app, it has a main that starts server and such stuff, if you have a test project, it has a main that run the tests, mixing both leads to this error. You need to create a new project and import the code that you want to test into it, there are several tutorials on how to do it. Sadly there is no (not that I know) way to put tests and code in same project.